# How to automatic confirm a call in telpromt confirm call alertview

Tags: ios, uialertview, telprompt

im trying to make a call through the telpromt command:

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"telprompt://123456789"]];

The problem is, that when de code is run, it displays an UIAlertView not of my property, asking to confirm the call.
It has to buttons: Cancel and Call.
I want to programatically press the call button in the AlertView.

Is it possible ?

Thanks !

Comment: That confirmation alert view is there for a reason...

Answer (score 1):

iOS does this to protect the user from malicious applications which would try to make random calls. Anytime there are integrations to the phone, SMS, twitter, facebook, etc. apple requires the user to accept and allow the application to perform the action. This is why the iPhone displays a `UIAlertView` asking the user wether they really want to make a call to the phone number you're providing.